# How can I merge two bands with different sizes using Rioxarray?

Tags: raster, merge, rasterio, xarray, rioxarray

I have two images that I want to combine as follows[image]

Expected result:

[image]

I tried to use the function rioxarray.merge.merge_arrays() in the following way but I got this error that I can't understand:

```py
>>> import rioxarray
>>> from rioxarray import merge
>>> b4_1 = rioxarray.open_rasterio("LC08_L1TP_204030_20200607_20200607_01_RT/LC08_L1TP_204030_20200607_20200607_01_RT_B4.TIF")
>>> b4_2 = rioxarray.open_rasterio("LC08_L1TP_204031_20200607_20200607_01_RT/LC08_L1TP_204031_20200607_20200607_01_RT_B4.TIF")
>>> merged = merge.merge_arrays([b4_1, b4_2], nodata=0.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ruben/anaconda3/envs/rs-aCoisa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rioxarray/merge.py", line 113, in merge_arrays
    **{key: val for key, val in input_kwargs.items() if val is not None},
  File "/home/ruben/anaconda3/envs/rs-aCoisa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasterio/merge.py", line 250, in merge
    boundless=False, masked=True, indexes=indexes)
  File "/home/ruben/anaconda3/envs/rs-aCoisa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rioxarray/merge.py", line 43, in read
    Image.fromarray(data_window[iii]).resize((width, height))
  File "/home/ruben/anaconda3/envs/rs-aCoisa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1905, in resize
    return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
ValueError: image has wrong mode
>>> b4_1
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 7811, x: 7691)>
[60074401 values with dtype=uint16]
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int64 1
  * y            (y) float64 4.899e+06 4.899e+06 ... 4.665e+06 4.665e+06
  * x            (x) float64 5.082e+05 5.082e+05 ... 7.389e+05 7.389e+05
    spatial_ref  int64 0
Attributes:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM:        63430
    STATISTICS_MEAN:           13305.927976843
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM:        0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV:         13401.114806381
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT:  100
    transform:                 (30.0, 0.0, 508185.0, 0.0, -30.0, 4899015.0)
    scale_factor:              1.0
    add_offset:                0.0
    grid_mapping:              spatial_ref
>>> b4_2
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 7831, x: 7701)>
[60306531 values with dtype=uint16]
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int64 1
  * y            (y) float64 4.741e+06 4.741e+06 ... 4.506e+06 4.506e+06
  * x            (x) float64 4.71e+05 4.71e+05 4.711e+05 ... 7.02e+05 7.02e+05
    spatial_ref  int64 0
Attributes:
    transform:     (30.0, 0.0, 470985.0, 0.0, -30.0, 4740615.0)
    scale_factor:  1.0
    add_offset:    0.0
    grid_mapping:  spatial_ref
```

What can I do to fix the problem? Or what alternative to I have to do this but still ending up with a xarray.DataArray?

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being a bug that was fixed in version 0.0.27

Comment: I have 10 files in a folder which I am trying to merge using the above rioxarray code, but the issue is the mosaic image is not coming properly (i.e. in mosaic image left part and right part is swapped). Can you suggest what could be the issue.

Comment: Only with that information is not easy to tell what the issue might be. I recommend you to post a Question on Rioxarray's repository page. https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray

Comment: I have raised the question. Following is the link,  https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/172.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with standard GDAL easily:

```py
import gdal
url="http://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data-landsat"
f1=f"/vsicurl/{url}/LC08/01/204/030/LC08_L1TP_204030_20200607_20200607_01_RT/" + \
      "LC08_L1TP_204030_20200607_20200607_01_RT_B4.TIF"


f2=f"/vsicurl/{url}/LC08/01/204/031/LC08_L1TP_204031_20200607_20200607_01_RT/" + \
      "LC08_L1TP_204031_20200607_20200607_01_RT_B4.TIF"

g = gdal.Warp("", [f1, f2], format="MEM",
            srcNodata=0)
```

You could also build this via a VRT file via gdalbuildvrt. On the shell this looks like

```
gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata 0 merge_them.vrt \
/vsicurl/http://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data-landsat/LC08/01/204/030/LC08_L1TP_204030_20200607_20200607_01_RT/LC08_L1TP_204030_20200607_20200607_01_RT_B4.TIF \
/vsicurl/http://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data-landsat/LC08/01/204/031/LC08_L1TP_204031_20200607_20200607_01_RT/LC08_L1TP_204031_20200607_20200607_01_RT_B4.TIF
```

The VRT file can then be imported directly by xarray and derivatives (or you can just `gdal_translate` to a GeoTIFF or whatever).